# Go and return a form

Tags: java, playframework-2.5

I want to send(save) a form to the Controller an back again to the view(edit). Currently the form-data will reach the controller, but not the view again. Could you exlain me whats happen?

```
@helper.inputText(articleForm("headline"), '_label -> "Überschrift"
                                         , '_showConstraints -> true
                                         , '_showErrors -> true
                                         , 'class -> "form-control"
                                         , 'label -> "label"
                                         , 'placeholder -> "sprechenden Titel eingeben"
                                         , Symbol("ng-model") -> "headline")
```

This is my controller:

```
Form<forms.ArticleForm> form = formFactory.form(forms.ArticleForm.class).bindFromRequest();

    if (form.hasErrors()) {
        Logger.info("form has errors");
        form.errors().forEach((k,v) -> Logger.info("key: {}, value: {}", k, v));

        return badRequest(views.html.NewArticle.render("check it", form));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I use ng, I have to fill the ng-models with ng. It havn´t work to fill a ng-model with a form.

```
@helper.inputText(articleForm("headline"), '_label -> "Überschrift"
                                     , '_showConstraints -> false
                                     , '_showErrors -> true
                                     , 'class -> "form-control"
                                     , 'label -> "label"
                                     , 'placeholder -> "sprechenden Titel eingeben"
                                     , 'oninput -> "verify()"
                                     )

<script>
function verify() {
    if(document.getElementById("headline").value.length >= 5 &&
       document.getElementById("textline").value.length >= 20){
        //alert("show");
        document.getElementById("btnSave").style.display = "block";
    }else{
        //alert("hide");
        document.getElementById("btnSave").style.display = "none";
    }
}
document.getElementById("btnSave").style.display = "none";
</script>
```